# Pause Open vSwitch (OVS) with the POX controller

Tags: sdn, openflow, openvswitch, pox

I am trying to pause an OVS with POX as described in

http://www.openvswitch.org/support/dist-docs/ovs-ofctl.8.txt

The respective add-flow command is (thanks to pchaigno for his answer):

```
sudo ovs-ofctl add-flow c2 "dl_dst=00:00:00:00:00:01,actions=controller(pause)"
```

(switch name c2)

But, I cannot find in the POX documentation a way of sending such command to the switch.

Comment: Did you make any progress with this?

Comment: No. I think that POX does not support it properly. If you need this I would recommend using another controller, such as Ryu for example.

Comment: I had some success sending remote commands to OVS using ssh, but I don't know how much further it is to get the remote command to come from POX. Also, there is the issue of plugging in passwords in ssh. I haven't used Ryu yet.

Comment: Well, you can use this module:https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko
if you want to connect through SSH with POX, and you can set-up public/private key based connection if you don't want passwords.